# React native rn-fetch-blob download with post method

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

i need to download a file(.pdf) which is coming from flask rest API by the code

```
return send_file(file_location, as_attachment=True)
```

i tried using RNFetchBlob

```
RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            addAndroidDownloads: {
                useDownloadManager: true, // <-- this is the only thing required
                // Optional, override notification setting (default to true)
                notification: false,
                // Optional, but recommended since android DownloadManager will fail when
                // the url does not contains a file extension, by default the mime type will be text/plain
                mime: 'application/pdf',
                description: 'File downloaded by download manager.',
            },
          })
          .fetch('POST', 'http://192.168.0.199:8000/v1/quote/view', data)
          .then((res)=>console.log('The file saved to ', res.path()))
          .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

but even when i mentioned POST method in the flask its is received as GET method

```
192.168.0.186 - - [11/Aug/2021 19:05:31] "GET /v1/quote/view HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might missing header in fetch as third params.

Comment: i was adding the data i wished to send as the third param,

Comment: updated it just now in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Xhirazi,

the order should be like this fetch(Method, URL, headers, body), fixed the issue